# Анализ соответствия дискретной выборки нормальному закону распределения

Tags: qt, c++

Есть дискретная выборка из 501 элемента (0.4042, 0.5967, 0.2124, 0.4576 и тд...). Провести анализ соответствия этой выборки нормальному закону распределения (распределения Гаусса).

Просмотрел много статей, но везде как то по-разному это описано да и в теор. вер. я слабоват... Кто поможет с алгоритмом решения? Или может у кого то было подобное занание?

Comment: Делается это очень просто с помощью статистического анализа выборки, находятся ассиметрия и эксцесс, которые потом сравниваются со значениями дисперсии этих самых ассиметрии и эксцесса с какими то коэффициэнтами, больше не подскажу, сейчас под рукой ничего нет, но копайте в сторону статистического анализа данных. Только не пойму, причем тут C++ и тем более Qt

Comment: Просто программу пишу на Qt, вот и добавил метки... если кто то поподробнее объяснит как решить задачу буду очень признателен...

Comment: Мы использовали критерий Пирсона. Промежуток разбивается на интервалы, считается теоретическая и экспериментальная вероятность попадения в интервал, суммируется по формуле и сравнивается по табличному значению

Comment: Эмпирические частоты - это количество попаданий в каждый из интервалов, а теоретические частоты - частоты, которые "должны быть", если бы случайная величина была нормально распределенной. Я правильно понимаю? Как на С++ посчитать теоретические частоты? Там вроде не обойтись без функции (интегральной) нормального распределения.

Comment: Всё верно. Для подсчета можно использовать функцию Лапласа. Взять либо интерполяцию по таблице, либо разложить в ряд.